# Memcache or Queue for Hits Logging

Tags: memcached, queue, message-queue

We have a busy website, which needs to log 'hits' about certain pages or API endpoints which are visited, to help populate stats, popularity grids, etc. The hits were logging aren't simple page hits, so can't use log parsing.

In the past, we've just directly logged to the database with an update query, but under heavy concurrency, this creates a database load that we don't want.

We are currently using Memcache but experiencing some issues with the stats not being quite accurate due to non-atomic updates.

So my question:

**Should we continue to use Memcache but improve atomic increments:**

1) When page is hit, create a memcache key such as "stats:pageid:3" and increment this each time we hit atomically

2) Write a batch script to cycle through all the memcache keys and create a batch update to database once every 10 mins

PROS: Less database hits, as we're only updating once per page per 10 mins (with however many hits in that 10 min period)

CONS: We can atomically increment the individual counters, but would still need a memcache key to store which pageids have had hits, to loop through and log. This won't be atomic, so when we flush the data to DB and reset everything, things may linger in this key. We could lose up to 10 mins of data.

**OR Use a queue/task system:**

1) When page is hit, add a job to the task queue
2) Task queue can then be rate limited and in the background process these 'hits' to the database.

PROS: Easy to code, we can scale up queue workers if required.

CONS: We're still hitting the database once per hit as each task would be processed individually, rather than 'summing' up all the hits.

Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR: use something designed for recording stats at high-traffic levels, such as [StatsD](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/) & [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/). The original StatsD is written in Javascript on top of NodeJS, which can be a little complex to setup (but there are easier ways to install it, [with a Docker container](https://github.com/dasch/docker-statsd)), or you can use a work-alike (not using NodeJS), that does the same function, such as one [written in GoLang](https://github.com/bitly/statsdaemon).

I've used the original StatsD and Graphite pair to great effect, plus it's making the pretty graphs (this was for 10's of millions of events per day).

Comment: Going to check this out now.. :)

Comment: My concern with this, is if our statsd backend went down we'd lose data until rectified, and we may not notice with it using UDP - any experience monitoring lost UDP packets, etc - is this possible?

Comment: There's an stats & command interface (https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/admin_interface.md) you can check to see if it's still returning info, much as you'd monitor any other service, like Memcached, or Apache.